# Как получить уведомление о срабатывании автозапуска с флешки?

Tags: c#, .net

Нужно реализовать программу, которая бы отправляла уведомления на почту при срабатывании функции автозапуска на флешке. Требуется просто записать факт срабатывания автозапуска, без перехвата самого процесса

Comment: Зачем такие сложности? Может, вы просто хотите отключить автозапуск?

Comment: неа, нужен именно перехват уведомления

Answer (score 0):

Решение для WinForms. В класс формы добавь следующее:

```
    private Message m;
    //признак USB 
    const int WM_DeviceChange = 0x219;
    //признак USB Is ON 
    const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000;
    //признак USB Is OFF 
    const int DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == WM_DeviceChange)
        {
            if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("USB is on");
            }
            if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE)
            {
                // usb отключено
                MessageBox.Show("USB is off");
            }
        }            
    }
```

То бишь переопределив эту процедуру - достигнешь желаемого

Comment: Но это же реагирует на вставку устройства, а не на срабатывание автозапуска.

Comment: Ну ведь если он настроен в Windows он же срабатывает при вставке флешки

Comment: (1) Автозапуск может быть временно отключен, (2) На флешке может не быть прописан автозапуск.

Comment: Ну я думаю это все пользовательские моменты настроечные

Comment: @VladD прав, не на всех устройствах имеется autorun и есть компьютеры, у которых в реестре отключен автозапуск